# React interface: Promise works but objects are still "is not defined"

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, reactjs, typescript

I have a simple React app, which calls an ASP.NET MVC controller which returns a simple object (see below). My problem is that I cannot write the values, because it's undefined.

I have made the following React interface which is the same as the returning data:

```
interface CreditData {
    Description: string;
    RatingData: {
        SummaryRating: number;
        Equity: number;
        Age: number;
        Employees: number;
        Type: number;
        Situation: number;
    };
    CompanyData: {
        VAT: string;
        Name: string;
        Address: string;
        Zipcode: string;
        City: string;
        Phone: string;
        Email: string;
        Startdate: string;
        Enddate: string;
        Employees: string;
    }

}
```

The interface the React class uses is:

```
interface CompanySearchState {
    loading: boolean;
    query: string;
    creditData: CreditData | null;
    showresult: boolean;
}
```

I have a button and when I click the button, the following code runs:

```
searchVat() {
    this.setState({ loading: true });

    var url = 'api/CreditData/creditrating?query=' + this.state.query;

    fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json() as Promise<CreditData>)
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            this.setState({ creditData: data, loading: false, showresult: true });
        });
}
```

Now, I don't get any errors on the call. However, in my layout I get a problem. I have the following view:

```
return <div><h1>Resultat for {this.state.creditData!.CompanyData!.Name}</h1>
                <div className='row'>
                    <div className='col-md-6'>
                        <h3>Rating</h3>
                        Fra 1-10: {this.state.creditData!.RatingData!.SummaryRating}
                        <h3>Data</h3>
                        {this.state.creditData!.Description}
                    </div>
                    <div className='col-md-6'>
                        <p>Test</p>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
```

My challenge is the following: `this.state` is correct and fine. When I hover it in debug mode, I can even see the values I want:

[image]

But in my view, the companyData object is "undefined", despite it works in the image before:

[image]

Now, the only difference I can see, is that one is `CompanyData` and other is `companyData`. But this doesn't help me, because I get another error if I write a small `companyData` inside the interface.

So my problem is: I want to access the companyData object, but it's undefined. I don't understand that, since it's working perfectly fine in the debugger when I hover `this.state`.

**My C# viewmodel returned**:

```
public class CreditData
{
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public CompanyData CompanyData { get; set; }
    public Rating RatingData { get; set; }
}

public class Rating
{
    public int SummaryRating { get; set; }
    public decimal Equity { get; set; }
    public decimal Age { get; set; }
    public decimal Employees { get; set; }
    public decimal Type { get; set; }
    public decimal Situation { get; set; }

}

public class CompanyData
{
    public string VAT { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Zipcode { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }

    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Startdate { get; set; }
    public string Enddate { get; set; }
    public string Employees { get; set; }

    public bool @protected { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }
    public string Addressco { get; set; }
    public int Industrycode { get; set; }
    public string Industrydesc { get; set; }
    public int Companycode { get; set; }
    public string Companydesc { get; set; }
    public string Creditstartdate { get; set; }
    public int? Creditstatus { get; set; }
    public bool Creditbankrupt { get; set; }
    public ApiOwners[] Owners { get; set; }
    public ApipPoductionunits[] Productionunits { get; set; }
    public int T { get; set; }
    public int Version { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: changing `this.state.creditData!.CompanyData!` to `this.state.creditData!.companyData!` didn't work?

Comment: @guijob I am not sure that's the underlying problem. But as you can see in the screenshots, this.state is fine and I can access the object data I need, but when I write it using the {this.state} in the view, it has undefined.

Comment: not exactly, this.state is fine and you can either access it using {this.state} in view, except for CompanyData property which is undefined because in fact your object doesn't have it. It has companyData and js is case sensitive

Comment: @guijob Ahhh, got it. I changed my interface to be lowercase letters and it worked. Do you want to make a short answer and then I can mark it? Basically the problem was I didn't respect lower/upper-case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `this.state` object has a `companyData` object and you're trying to access an `CompanyData` (with capital C), but javascript is case sensitive so will need to lower-case it:

Wrong:

```
this.state.creditData!.CompanyData!
```

Right:

```
this.state.creditData!.companyData!
```